# create new object in php

Tags: php, magento, instance

I understand that PHP doesn't allow me to create a new instance of ClassB inside my ClassA, if the creation is not inside the scope of a function. Or I just don't understand...

```
class ClassA {

const ASD = 0;
protected $_asd = array();
//and so on

protected $_myVar = new ClassB(); // here I get *syntax error, unexpected 'new'* underlining 'new'

// functions and so on
}
```

Do I need some kind of constructor, or is there a way to actually create the object instance in a free way as I desire, as I am used to do in Java or C#. Or is using Singleton the only closest solution to my approach?

P.S. ClassB is located in the same package and folder as ClassA.

Comment: And where's the code for `ClassB`?

Comment: @sal00m - good question. I updated my post. Look at the *P.S.*. :)

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php   class attributes can be intialized with constant values only. Expression results are expressly forbidden. You need to do what you want in the classA constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

As such, you will need to instantiate `$_myVar` in your [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php):

```
protected $_myVar;    

public function __contruct() {
   $this->_myVar = new ClassB();
}
```

Comment: So I guess this object is created at compile time and I can use it in the rest of the class simply as `$_myVar->someFunctionFromClassB()`, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, don't forget the *this* prefix, of course: `$this->_myVar->someFunctionFromClassB()`

Comment: @JasonMcCreary - good tip! Old habits from Java die hard... I have to get used to the PHP syntax.

Comment: You should read the docs as an introduction. Then reread them after you write some code :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a constructor (see below)

```
class ClassA {

    const ASD = 0;
    protected $_asd = array();
    //and so on

    protected $_myVar; // initialization not allowed directly here

        public function __contruct() {
            $this->_myVar = new ClassB();
        }
    }
```