# Instance Class inside construct

Tags: php, oop

I need to instance 2 or more classes on top of my controller class, so I can use them with `$this->filter` or `$this->logger_instance` inside any method of my controller class. Right now it is not letting me, I get an error. (I do not want to extend the class if possible.) Is it okay to instance in construct if it is possible.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_NEW in controller.php

(I am in the process of transferring my coding habits from procedural to OOP so I am really bad at it.)

```
class ID_Controller
{
    public $input;
    public $register_attempt = 2;
    public $maximum_attempts = 3;
    public $log_data_attempts = 2;
    public $query_log_file_path;
    public $sql_filtering = true;
    public $xss_filtering = true;
    public $sql_register_attempt = 3;
    public $xss_register_attempt = 6;

    public $filter = new ID_Algorithm;
    public $logger_instance = new ID_Logger;

    function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [create new object in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793586/create-new-object-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try initializing these classes through the `__construct()` method?

```
/*
    If the two classes are located in seperate files, be sure to require them:
*/
require("ID_Algorithm Page");
require("ID_Lodder Page");
class ID_Controller {
    /* previous lines here */ 
    /* 
    Comment out the next two lines and initiate them within the construct class 
    */
    // public $filer = new ID_Algorithm;
    // public $logger_instance; 
    public $filer;
    public $logger_instance
    public function __construct(){
        $this->filter = new ID_Algorithm;
        $this->logger_instance = new ID_Logger;
    }
}
```

Then when calling:

```
$Class = new ID_Controller();
```

this will set the necessary internal pointers correctly.